# Setting nested attributes in the model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Log model that belongs to User and Firm. For setting this I have this code in the logs_controller's create action.

```
 def create
     @log = Log.new(params[:log])
     @log.user = current_user
     @log.firm = current_firm
     @log.save
   end
```

current_user and current_firm are helper methods from the application_helper.rb

While this works it makes the controller fat. How can I move this to the model?

Comment: Personally I don't think what you have here is fat, there might be good reasons to code it exactly as you have. You might want this in fact, to avoid putting user and firm in the attr_accessible for the model.

Comment: It's like this in too many places. Initially I was fine with it, but now it to much  ;)

Comment: I agree about `attr_accessible`. One reason I like this in a worker class is it helps enforce a single point of entry for creating model instances, as well as enforcing that the necessary relations will be setup (though validation will also help with this; the worker method's signature helps act as a guide). It also makes testing the functionality that will be found in the controller for manipulating models dead simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this sort of functionality belongs in a 'worker' class in `lib/`. My action method might look like

```
def create
  @log = LogWorker.create(params[:log], current_user, current_firm)
end
```

And then I'd have a module in `lib/log_worker.rb` like

```
module LogWorker
  extend self

  def create(params, user, firm)
    log      = Log.new(params)
    log.user = user
    log.firm = firm

    log.save
  end
end
```

This is a simplified example; I typically namespace everything, so my method might actually be in `MyApp::Log::Manager.create(...)`

Comment: I really like this approach. I felt it was a bit awkward in the model and in the controller. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No difference: You can refactor the code:

```
def create
  @log = Log.new(params[:log].merge(:user => current_user, :firm => current_firm)
  @log.save
end
```

And your Log have to:

```
attr_accessible :user, :firm
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much shorter, but the responsibility for the handling of current_user falls to the controller in MVC

```
def create
 @log = Log.create(params[:log].merge(
   :user => current_user,
   :firm => current_firm))
end
```

*EDIT*

If you don't mind violating MVC a bit, here's a way to do it:

```
# application_controller.rb
before_filter :set_current
def set_current
  User.current = current_user
  Firm.current = current_firm
end

# app/models/user.rb
cattr_accessor :current

# app/models/firm.rb
cattr_accessor :current

# app/models/log.rb
before_save :set_current
def set_current
  self.firm = Firm.current
  self.user = User.current
end

# app/controllers/log_controller.rb
def create
  @log = Log.create(params[:log])
end
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. The problem was a bit simplified in the question. I have more complex things going on. I just want to get it out. ;)

Comment: @Lyngstad I updated with a clean, but non-MVC way to handle that may be interesting to you if this kind of code is all over the place